# How to get radio buttons to update histogram Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, histogram

I have a hard time getting radio buttons to update the histogram when using matplotlib.animation.

I'd like to show random sampling from a normal distribution. It starts with n=20. The animation works for n = 20. The radio buttons add a few more options: n=50, n=100, n=200.

Below are my codes. Thank you for your help!

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 20
x = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1,size=n)

# create the function that will do the plotting, where curr is the current frame
def update(curr):
    # check if animation is at the last frame, and if so, stop the animation a
    if curr == n: 
        a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.5)
    plt.hist(x[:curr], bins=bins)
    plt.axis([-7,5,0,30])
    plt.gca().set_title('Sampling the Normal Distribution')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
    plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,25])   

#Plot    
fig = plt.figure()

#Create radio button
rax = plt.axes([0.01, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15])
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('n=50', 'n=100', 'n=200'))

def samplesize(label):
    if label == 50:
        n=50
        a=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)  
    elif label == 100:
        n=100
        a=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)  
    else:        
        n=200
        a=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)  
    plt.draw()  


radio.on_clicked(samplesize)    
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)  
aax = plt.axes([0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])   
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on Jupyter Notebook. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or is it not interacitve? Make sure to inclue `%matplotlib widget` at the beginning of your notebook  (you need to install `ipympl`).

Comment: When I used my class jupyter notebook, I didn't get error it didn't show the graph or anything. I tried it on my desktop and it worked when I commented out %matplotlib widget.

Comment: Does your piece of code show a plot? I have `python` `3.7.7` and `matplotlib` `3.2.2` installed and for me it works both with jupyter notebooks and as a normal script.
Try to comment all the animation parts out and just plot an empty figure and than add the other functionality step by step to see where it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The code is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774327/7570817).
For some reason you always have to click twice before the figure updates, but otherwise it should work fine.

```py
# %matplotlib widget  # for jupyter notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

n_max = 200
x_curr = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, size=n_max)
bins = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.5)

def animate(i):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_title('Sampling the Normal Distribution')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    ax.set_xlabel('Value')
    ax.annotate('n = {}'.format(i), [3, 25])
    ax.axis([-7, 5, 0, 30])
    ax.hist(x_curr[:i], bins=bins)


anis = []
def on_click(event):
    n = int(event[2:])

    for ani in anis:
        ani.event_source.stop()
        anis.remove(ani)
        del ani

    print(n)
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=n, repeat=False)
    anis.append(ani)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()

rax = plt.axes([0.01, 0.2, 0.15, 0.25])
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('n=20', 'n=50', 'n=100', 'n=200'))
radio.on_clicked(on_click)
animate(20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to work on my question. I'm not sure what I missed, but it just shows a blank plot with radio buttons when I run it in my Jupyter notebook.